# Symphonic vs. symphony

Tags: meaning, differences, terminology, music

Is there any clear line between a *symphony* and *symphonic*?

For long, I thought that a symphony was simply a "song" played by a symphonic orchestra. Then I realized that more often than not, the ensemble is actually also called *symphony* orchestra.

As a lot of this terminology is used on pages from all around the world (often translated by non-native speakers), I'd like to get some final clarification from an educated native speaker. Will you?

And to make the question complete, speaking of an ensemble, is there any difference in meaning in the following (and are they all equally correct): *symphonic, symphonic orchestra, symphony, symphony orchestra, philharmonic, philharmonic orchestra* (I know that most orchestras will have their "standardized" English names but speaking of a general classical orchestra, are all the terms identical?)

Comment: symphonic is an adjective, symphony is a noun.

Comment: @Jim That's exactly what I thought before I realized that sympony was used as an adjective as well. Therefore I asked this question.

Comment: yes, a noun can be used as an adjective- bread box, car port, wish list, and symphony orchestra.   It's called a symphony orchestra because it is an orchestra that plays symphonies, just as a bread box is a box that holds bread.

Comment: The Grove dictionary has a good writeup on the usage of the word in different historical contexts [here](http://www.oxfordmusiconline.com/subscriber/article/grove/music/27254), but it may require a subscription and probably has a lot more detail than you're looking for.

Comment: @Jim I get your point. I was more concerned about the use than grammar here. I just simply was not sure whether there was any preference in terms of what form to use. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Cameron Thanks. But although I am curious, I'm not curious enough to subscribe :)

Comment: @Malis Understandable. To sum it up, *symphony* used to be synonymous for *overture*, but now refers to "extended work for orchestra. …The adjective ‘symphonic’ applied to a work implies that it is extended and thoroughly developed." In the US, *symphony* can also mean *symphony orchestra*. *Symphonic orchestra* is a more rare construction (and has no entry in the Grove dictionary, which is considered a standard musical reference). *Philharmonic* just means *a musical organization*, with one incarnation being a standard European orchestra (e.g. The London Philharmonic).

Comment: Also, if you haven't yet, check your local library to see if they have an OED subscription (which will also give you access to the Grove dictionary). That's how I have access, and it's pretty common, from what I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Symphonic" is an adjective, "symphony" a noun, "symphony orchestra" a noun phrase. Whether an orchestra is called a "symphony orchestra," a "philharmonic orchestra," or something else is purely a matter of the creator's preference. There are top-ranked orchestras with both names (Vienna Philharmonic, Boston Symphony, etc.), and there's no systematic difference in composition or repertoire.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. To sum it up - all of those terms I suggest are pretty much identical as far as we aren't speaking of a specific orchestra that has (obviously) a single specific official name (which can be any of those suggested). Right?

Comment: OT: Why can't I upvote your answer as useful without enough reputation? Consider it upvoted anyway.

Comment: The only one that isn't quite right is *symphonic* used by itself.

Comment: There is symphonic music, but I've never heard of a symphonic orchestra.